# Troubleshooting 'coroutine not awaited' error in Clash of Clans API async-await function in Python

Tags: python, function, api, async-await, coroutine

I'm studying the API of the mobile game Clash of Clans, and the other day I encountered such a problem. The userClashData = await clash_api.get_player() function outputs a coroutine that is not instantiated and data from which is retrieved only using asynchronous functions. I apologize for the possible stupidity that I could have done while writing this handler, but it’s not difficult for anyone, please help with solving this problem. Source part:

`                    try:

```
                    userClashData = await clash_api.get_player()

                    clash_profile_img = render.clash_profile(banner, int(userClashData.trophies), userClashData)

                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, clash_profile_img, caption=f''' {u2name}
```

User Stats from Clash of Clans''')

```
                    render.output_cache_clear()

                except (coc.NotFound, coc.ClashOfClansException):

                    bot.reply_to(message, '❌ User data not found')

                    render.output_cache_clear()`
```

`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Commands_CheckUserClashProfile' was never awaited

task(*args, **kwargs)

RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

I had an idea to create a team inside a bot to check and display a photo with data about a person's profile from the Clash of Clans game.  I have already set up both the render and commit of the person tag.  My only problem is the output from the coroutine, which is constantly accompanied by "RuntimeError"

I'm sorry, if problem is very stupid or easily solved. Thanks

Comment: Where/what is `Commands_CheckUserClashProfile` and how is it used in the code?

Comment: @MichaelButscher The function is used automatically through the human message handler, and more specifically, the specified command in the processing list - commands = ["", "", "", ...]